# cannot open source file GL/glut.h in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows desktop

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, glut

Like the title says it gives me this error : "ERROR: cannot open source file "GL/glut.h" .

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Project paths]

[image: Includes Folder]

It gives me the error on the GL/glut.h line :

```
#include <windows.h>  // For MS Windows
#include <GL/glut.h>  // GLUT, includes glu.h and gl.h
```

I installed windows sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLUT is a 3rd party library, i.e. it's not part of OpenGL. As such its not part of the Windows system APIs and hence not part of the standard Windows SDK.

Go to http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download , follow the link to the prebuilt Windows library packages (http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/), download the MSVC build (http://files.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/development/GLUT/freeglut-MSVC.zip).

**DO NOT UNPACK THE HEADERS AND LIBRARIES INTO YOUR SDK INSTALLATION OR THE WINDOWS DIRECTORIES!**

Unpack the library package either into a location dedicated for third party libraries (you'll have to create that), or, if you plan to use the library for one project only, unpack it into your project's directory. The DLL goes in the same directory as the built .EXE.